# invisible text on setError() in android

Tags: java, android

I am using setError() method in EditText in android. It does show the popup but the text is invisible. It seems like text has the same color like its background which is white. I used following code to make it work but still the text is not visible.

```
int ecolor = 65793;
String estring = "Input is incorrect";
ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);
customPriceInput.setError(ssbuilder);
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: i have the same error. hopefully my comment bumps this somehow

Comment: @Tim If you want to bump it up, try up-voting the question with the up array next to it.

Comment: @Peter alright. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

```
private EditText adTitle;
// ....
adTitle.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>hello</font>"));
```

extract from: [Changing the look and feel of default .setError("I dont like your pink color");](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269503/changing-the-look-and-feel-of-default-seterrori-dont-like-your-pink-color)

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22920

this worked for me. (the second comment)

"#2 shardu...@gmail.com
Hi,

I was able to reproduce this on my Nexus S running Android 4.0.3.

Here's how I made it work.
1. Create a theme with: 

        @android:color/primary_text_light

2.Apply MyApp theme to my application from manifest."