# Changing the look and feel of default .setError("I dont like your pink color");

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to change the look and feel and the colour of .setError(""); thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll assume that you mean

> EditText.setError()

Extend TextView in your own custom class and override setError() to do whatever you want.  You could start with the Android source to see the default implementation.

[EditText source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setError%28java.lang.CharSequence,android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Comment: Thank You, let me get started on that! I thought it .setError("") was self explanatory, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: And I don't know why the down voting!