# Auto fading of edittext set error property

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I tried this but couldent think of any ideas how to make a showerror message property to auto fade after a certain point of time. If anybody has any ideas please share. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void run()
                                {
                                    editText.setError(null);
                                }
                        }, 1000);
```

Comment: by making it null the error symbol still stands as it is in the  right hand side of the edittext box

Comment: i am sorry but i confused the null parameter with something else. It works perfect! Thanks for the heads up

Comment: just another thing i would like you to ask, can this fading be delayed like its almost instant, can it be like the balloon fades inn windows 7 in the notification bar. I hope i make you understand this.

Comment: I got it , it is default , I don't think so we can fade an error out/in
but I think with text might be you'll be able to do it with Alpha
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15362063/1292177
or you can customize your own TextView
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13270241/1292177